# how to load store from response without specifying url in store

Tags: extjs4

How to load data from response which is already i have and how read the arrived response and use that response data for loading store in extjs. I have post my response here. Thanks in advance.

```
{"preparedSandData":[{"preparedsandId":57,"activeClay":1,"afs":1,"compactability":1,"date":"12-10-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":1,"gcs":1,"loi":1,"moisture":1,"quantity":1,"shatterIndex":1,"shearStrength":1,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":1,"temperature":1,"time":"12-10-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":1,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":58,"activeClay":2,"afs":2,"compactability":2,"date":"12-11-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":2,"gcs":2,"loi":2,"moisture":2,"quantity":2,"shatterIndex":2,"shearStrength":2,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":2,"temperature":2,"time":"12-11-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":2,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":59,"activeClay":3,"afs":3,"compactability":3,"date":"12-12-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":3,"gcs":3,"loi":3,"moisture":3,"quantity":3,"shatterIndex":3,"shearStrength":3,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":3,"temperature":3,"time":"12-12-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":3,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":60,"activeClay":4,"afs":4,"compactability":4,"date":"12-13-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":4,"gcs":4,"loi":4,"moisture":4,"quantity":4,"shatterIndex":4,"shearStrength":4,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":4,"temperature":4,"time":"12-13-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":4,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":61,"activeClay":5,"afs":5,"compactability":5,"date":"12-14-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":5,"gcs":5,"loi":5,"moisture":5,"quantity":5,"shatterIndex":5,"shearStrength":5,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":5,"temperature":5,"time":"12-14-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":5,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":62,"activeClay":6,"afs":6,"compactability":6,"date":"12-15-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":6,"gcs":6,"loi":6,"moisture":6,"quantity":6,"shatterIndex":6,"shearStrength":6,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":6,"temperature":6,"time":"12-15-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":6,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":63,"activeClay":7,"afs":7,"compactability":7,"date":"12-16-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":7,"gcs":7,"loi":7,"moisture":7,"quantity":7,"shatterIndex":7,"shearStrength":7,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":7,"temperature":7,"time":"12-16-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":7,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":64,"activeClay":8,"afs":8,"compactability":8,"date":"12-17-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":8,"gcs":8,"loi":8,"moisture":8,"quantity":8,"shatterIndex":8,"shearStrength":8,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":8,"temperature":8,"time":"12-17-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":8,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":65,"activeClay":9,"afs":9,"compactability":9,"date":"12-18-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":9,"gcs":9,"loi":9,"moisture":9,"quantity":9,"shatterIndex":9,"shearStrength":9,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":9,"temperature":9,"time":"12-18-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":9,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":66,"activeClay":10,"afs":10,"compactability":10,"date":"12-19-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":10,"gcs":10,"loi":10,"moisture":10,"quantity":10,"shatterIndex":10,"shearStrength":10,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":10,"temperature":10,"time":"12-19-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":10,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":67,"activeClay":11,"afs":11,"compactability":11,"date":"12-20-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":11,"gcs":11,"loi":11,"moisture":11,"quantity":11,"shatterIndex":11,"shearStrength":11,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":11,"temperature":11,"time":"12-20-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":11,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":68,"activeClay":12,"afs":12,"compactability":12,"date":"12-21-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":12,"gcs":12,"loi":12,"moisture":12,"quantity":12,"shatterIndex":12,"shearStrength":12,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":12,"temperature":12,"time":"12-21-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":12,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":69,"activeClay":13,"afs":13,"compactability":13,"date":"12-22-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":13,"gcs":13,"loi":13,"moisture":13,"quantity":13,"shatterIndex":13,"shearStrength":13,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":13,"temperature":13,"time":"12-22-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":13,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":70,"activeClay":14,"afs":14,"compactability":14,"date":"12-23-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":14,"gcs":14,"loi":14,"moisture":14,"quantity":14,"shatterIndex":14,"shearStrength":14,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":14,"temperature":14,"time":"12-23-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":14,"username":"manoj","sampleId":23},{"preparedsandId":71,"activeClay":1,"afs":1,"compactability":1,"date":"12-10-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":1,"gcs":1,"loi":1,"moisture":1,"quantity":1,"shatterIndex":1,"shearStrength":1,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":1,"temperature":1,"time":"12-10-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":1,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":72,"activeClay":2,"afs":2,"compactability":2,"date":"12-11-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":2,"gcs":2,"loi":2,"moisture":2,"quantity":2,"shatterIndex":2,"shearStrength":2,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":2,"temperature":2,"time":"12-11-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":2,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":73,"activeClay":3,"afs":3,"compactability":3,"date":"12-12-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":3,"gcs":3,"loi":3,"moisture":3,"quantity":3,"shatterIndex":3,"shearStrength":3,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":3,"temperature":3,"time":"12-12-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":3,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":74,"activeClay":4,"afs":4,"compactability":4,"date":"12-13-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":4,"gcs":4,"loi":4,"moisture":4,"quantity":4,"shatterIndex":4,"shearStrength":4,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":4,"temperature":4,"time":"12-13-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":4,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":75,"activeClay":5,"afs":5,"compactability":5,"date":"12-14-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":5,"gcs":5,"loi":5,"moisture":5,"quantity":5,"shatterIndex":5,"shearStrength":5,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":5,"temperature":5,"time":"12-14-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":5,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":76,"activeClay":6,"afs":6,"compactability":6,"date":"12-15-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":6,"gcs":6,"loi":6,"moisture":6,"quantity":6,"shatterIndex":6,"shearStrength":6,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":6,"temperature":6,"time":"12-15-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":6,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":77,"activeClay":7,"afs":7,"compactability":7,"date":"12-16-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":7,"gcs":7,"loi":7,"moisture":7,"quantity":7,"shatterIndex":7,"shearStrength":7,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":7,"temperature":7,"time":"12-16-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":7,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":78,"activeClay":8,"afs":8,"compactability":8,"date":"12-17-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":8,"gcs":8,"loi":8,"moisture":8,"quantity":8,"shatterIndex":8,"shearStrength":8,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":8,"temperature":8,"time":"12-17-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":8,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":79,"activeClay":9,"afs":9,"compactability":9,"date":"12-18-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":9,"gcs":9,"loi":9,"moisture":9,"quantity":9,"shatterIndex":9,"shearStrength":9,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":9,"temperature":9,"time":"12-18-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":9,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":80,"activeClay":10,"afs":10,"compactability":10,"date":"12-19-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":10,"gcs":10,"loi":10,"moisture":10,"quantity":10,"shatterIndex":10,"shearStrength":10,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":10,"temperature":10,"time":"12-19-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":10,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":81,"activeClay":11,"afs":11,"compactability":11,"date":"12-20-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":11,"gcs":11,"loi":11,"moisture":11,"quantity":11,"shatterIndex":11,"shearStrength":11,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":11,"temperature":11,"time":"12-20-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":11,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":82,"activeClay":12,"afs":12,"compactability":12,"date":"12-21-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":12,"gcs":12,"loi":12,"moisture":12,"quantity":12,"shatterIndex":12,"shearStrength":12,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":12,"temperature":12,"time":"12-21-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":12,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":83,"activeClay":13,"afs":13,"compactability":13,"date":"12-22-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":13,"gcs":13,"loi":13,"moisture":13,"quantity":13,"shatterIndex":13,"shearStrength":13,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":13,"temperature":13,"time":"12-22-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":13,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0},{"preparedsandId":84,"activeClay":14,"afs":14,"compactability":14,"date":"12-23-2012 12:00:00 AM","deadClay":14,"gcs":14,"loi":14,"moisture":14,"quantity":14,"shatterIndex":14,"shearStrength":14,"shift":"Morning","splittingStrength":14,"temperature":14,"time":"12-23-2012 12:00:00 AM","totalClay":14,"username":"manoj","sampleId":0}],"success":true}
```

Comment: By the way, you should really accept more answers.

Comment: yes sure i what to accept answers but i don't know how to accept thanks in advance

Comment: you have a small checker on the left of the answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
//Result being your response from the request
//you need to decode it
var response = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
var records = [];
Ext.Array.each(response.preparedSandData, function(recordData) {
    //each record needs to  be instantiated to a model  
    var record = Ext.ModelManager.create(recordData, '*ModelClass*');
    records.push(record);
});
//load all records at once
store.loadRecords(records);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply But i want to use that response in other page and i can't access that response object in other page. How to achieve that please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What actually happening with me , I have Search criteria screen and there is other screen is chart. Now i search something from search criteria screen and  i got the response. with success of search i am creating new chart and that response data(which already i have in response) should load in store. Is that possible to load data in store from response from other page if possible then how to achieve this please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't really have to look at it as two different pages.. ,If it's in the same extjs application object the store is global, so you can load it from anywhere you like. You can access it by Ext.getStore('uniqueStoreId'); You can set yourself the id by adding the storeId to the store configuration.

Comment: thanks that's fine but i want to read store from response i have response as i have upload my response above. How to encode or decode response and load that decoded response in store. Thanks in advence

Comment: that's what the code from my answer does... it decodes the answer, creates records from each item of the array, and then adds the records to any store you want ... You either don't understand what i mean, or you have difficulties expressing what you actually want, because this is what i understand. Cheers